# Can we can get (Job Title) by signing in to Google Auth in the response object

Tags: reactjs, google-authentication, google-people-api

Can we get the job title info after signing in with google auth in my response object. I am only getting  the basic info like email, photo URL, name

Comment: Can you provide more information about your issue? What API method are you using? Please provide the relevant parts of the code you're using. Do the `people` you are trying to retrieve have this information added to their resource?